# Django library for consuming XML service and automatically mapping into Django model object?

Tags: django, web-services, rest, jaxb, pyxb

Is there a jax-b equivalent in Django?
I would like to consume a few different xml restful services that other people have written (publicly available) and parse them into Django model objects, automatically.
Upon further review, my specific use case is generating Django model objects from standard RSS and Atom feeds.

Thank you!

Update: does this link fit the bill as the de facto standard way to accomplish my task?

It uses PyXB to map schemas to python.

```
http://robertnewmanconsulting.com/blog/2013/apr/03/using-pyxb-django-validate-xml-docs-xsd-schemas/
```

Don't know how popular this package is:

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-rss2rest/0.1
```

This utility seems to be more popular but does it map to django models?

```
https://code.google.com/p/feedparser/
```

Update update:

OK now my question is, how do you generate a Django model from an existing Python class? The frameworks listed above convert the raw xml into a regular Python class.  I just would like this final step.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jax-b, but [Django Rest Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers.html) is capable of handing XML.

Comment: Does Django rest handle the mapping automatically though?  I've seen that you have to specify the model and then django rest can serialize and deserialize.  I want to have a library that can either take an .xsd schema file or the raw xml itself and then automatically map these to django models, or something similar. If I specify a django model beforehand to deserialize the xml stream into I'm not sure how hard it would be to ensure that the xml deserializes correctly.

Comment: I'd rather the library deserialize into an 'temporary' model object, and then working with the 'temporary' object, I can create my final model using my 'temporary' model object.  Deserializing from xml straight into my final model object may be hard no?